How do you log in?
Somehow I got logged out of my account on another device and I can't figure out how to get back into it.  If I click "join this community" it creates a new fake profile for me.  I can delete the profile, but as soon as I try again it does the same thing.
I don't see any login button, or anything else that might lead me to login to an existing profile.  What am I missing, and how can I get my other device logged back in under this profile?


When you are not logged in the top-bar should show a log-in button next to the signup button as shown above.
If you don't see this, try deleting browser history to clear cookies and it should work.

@MichaelHall I am glad I could help, thank you for updating the answer!
